# Apple App Review Location Services Consent Issue

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, location-services

App Store Connection reviewers informed me that my build is in violation of the below rule:

```
Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access their location but does not clarify the use of the location in the applicable purpose string.
```

...even though I have included the following key value pair in my App's Info.plist:

> Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description: Access to location
>   while the app is in use is required initialize your map feed.

...and I am therefore unable to replicate the issue in the screenshot they shared with me below:

[image]

Here is the dialogue I have always seen on the same Device (iPad) iOS 13.3:

[image]

My understanding of [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocationwheninuseusagedescription) is that I only need `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` as my application only requires access to a user's location when in the foreground.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before or have an idea what the source of it is? Many thanks!

Edit: Below is the code governing this experience.

```
func requestLocationAuthorization(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        let locationManagerAuthorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        let appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary![kCFBundleNameKey as String] as! String

        switch locationManagerAuthorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            LNTLocationManager.sharedInstance.requestAuthorization()
        case .denied:
            let alertString = "To initialize your map feed to your location, enable " + appName + " to use your location while using the app."
            presentSettingsAlert(with: alertString, completion: nil)
        default:
            break
        }

        completion?()
        return
    }
```

In the case where I don't enable location access, I always see the below prompt, not the one that the Reviewers experience:

[image]

Comment: On your iPad, go to `Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services`, find your app, and change it to **Never**. Then run your app and see if you get that "default" prompt (I expect you will). What Apple wants is for your code to check Authorization status ... if the user had initially said "Don't Allow" - or changed it in settings - you should show your *own* message with enough information to make it clear why you need Location access.

Comment: In my opinion your location usage description is not that clear so 1 can have a clear understanding why it should be allowed. Please update this description: `Access to location while the app is in use is required initialize your map feed` to be something more specific. I think you should write you description in this format: `[App_Name] requires your location to [purpose_of_location]`

Comment: @DonMag thank you for your thoughtful response. Unfortunately, I'm unable to replicate the issue following your recommendation. I've edited my question to provide more context on my app's behavior in the case of a user that did not authorize location. Let me know what you think if you can. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog they are displaying is what appears *from the system* the first time you say `startUpdatingLocation` at a time when `locationServicesEnabled` is `false`. It has nothing to do with the `denied` alert that *you* are putting up.

Note that this has nothing to do with user authorization! It has to do with location services being turned off *as a whole*. Apple, while testing, checks for that circumstance. It looks like your app doesn't.

To prevent the system dialog from appearing, always check whether `locationServicesEnabled` is `true`, and if it isn't, *go no further*.

(However, having said that, the message coming to you from Apple is incorrect if they think that the dialog they show is supposed to include your usage description. It isn't. It always looks the way they show it. You might want to write back and tell them that. They might have some people working for them right now who don't know what they're doing.)

Comment: Hi @matt, thank you for your insight here. This is the source of the issue - and important reminder to consider device-level settings instead of app-level ones. I'll be sure to inform the Reviewers that they don't seem to know what they're doing. Again, much appreciated.